# Mutliple users editing single document in wordspress

Tags: plugins, categories, users, user-roles, documentation

My team is working on wordpress for documentation purpose. No I want to create a document with multiple chapters and different team members should edit different chapters. One chapter opened by one team member should be locked for others.
In short I want multiple users to work on a single document simultaneously. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to create Custom post type, and then handling top level items as "documents" and its child items like "chapters". Every user can edit his own chapter then.

It would require some front-end setup - list only top-level items (`post_parent=0`) in main query, and looping through child posts on its single page. And some redirects, when visitor accidentally visit child item page, etc.